# how to deploy multiple websites and each with app folder magento2?

Tags: magento2, deployment

i develop magento2 modules, and "common practice" for module development is to install new magento2 everytime for new module. This is tedious and space consuming.

I'm trying to use the multiple website facility in Magento2 to achieve something that'll allow me to have one main installation and multiple sub-folders according to the module I'm developing and each that sub-folder would supposedly have it's own app directory and the back-end for each sub-folder will list the module in that directory only (in `sub-folder/app/code/`).

What I've tried so far is, created a website and default store/view and created new folder inside (website2), I copied `index.php` `.htaccess app`, `pub`, `var`, `bin` folder in that directory. (No luck yet)

Is this possible or is there a better way?
If possible, how can it be done? to have multiple instances, each with app dir, of one main installation.

Comment: Did you ever sort this?

Comment: No i haven't yet